# MySQL sub-query performance 5.0 to 5.1 (and later)

Tags: mysql, subquery, database-performance

I have encountered the following query as part of a PHP application. The query runs quickly (less than 1 second) in mysql 5.0, but in mysql 5.1 and later it takes about 7 minutes to complete.

The returned result is only 3 rows, but when I do an `strace` on the mysqld process on the 5.1 server as it's running this query, I can see it continuously reading data from the `Event` table for several minutes (a table with only 7000 rows at 200 bytes per row) -- presumably re-reading it multiple times.

So the question is, what's different here that I'm running into, and how can I modify things (either the query or better yet some MySQL settings) so that this will run under 5.1 as fast as it runs under 5.0.

---

### Referenced Data

**The query to blame**

```
SELECT S.Sections_ID, S.Sections_Name, S.Sections_CustomURL
FROM Sections S
WHERE S.Sections_Status = 'Active'
    AND S.Sections_Name!='Hidden'
    AND S.Sections_ParentID = 0
    AND S.Sections_MainSection = 1
    AND (
        SELECT COUNT(MainEvent.Event_ID) AS tot
        FROM Event MainEvent, Event_Section ES
        WHERE ES.EventSection_EventID=MainEvent.Event_ID
            AND ES.EventSection_SectionID=S.Sections_ID
            AND (
                (MainEvent.Event_DateTime > '2011-12-27 18:05:00')
                OR
                    (
                        (
                        SELECT ChildEvent.Event_DateTime
                        FROM Event ChildEvent
                        WHERE ChildEvent.Event_ParentEventID=MainEvent.Event_ID
                        ORDER BY ChildEvent.Event_DateTime DESC LIMIT 1
                        ) > '2011-12-27 18:05:00'
                    )
                )
            AND (MainEvent.Event_ParentEventID=0 or MainEvent.Event_ParentEventID IS NULL) 
            AND (MainEvent.Event_Status='Active' or MainEvent.Event_Status='Canceled') 
            AND MainEvent.Event_ID IN (
                SELECT
                Event_Website.EventWebsite_EventID
                FROM Event_Website 
                WHERE Event_Website.EventWebsite_CompanyID='3'
            )
        )>0
ORDER BY S.Sections_Order ASC, S.Sections_Name ASC
```

The referenced tables have the following number of rows

Sections: 60
Event: 7000
Event_Section: 7000
Event_Website: 15000

Below is the `EXPLAIN` for the above query from the 5.0 (fast) and 5.1 (slow) server.
*Clipped for space; hopefully I didn't clip out anything useful.*

**SLOW (5.1)**

```
+----+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | table         | type        | possible_keys              | key                    | key_len | ref                              | rows | Extra                       |
+----+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | S             | ref         | Sections_ParentID          | Sections_ParentID      | 5       | const                            |   10 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  2 | MainEvent     | ref_or_null | PRIMARY,Event_DateTime,... | Event_ParentID         | 5       | const                            | 4582 | Using where                 |
|  2 | ES            | ref         | EventSection_EventID       | EventSection_EventID   | 10      | MainEvent.Event_ID,S.Sections_ID |    1 | Using where; Using index    |
|  4 | Event_Website | ref         | EventWebsite_CompanyID     | EventWebsite_CompanyID | 4       | const                            | 4421 | Using where                 |
|  3 | ChildEvent    | index       | Event_ParentID             | Event_DateTime         | 8       | NULL                             |    1 | Using where                 |
+----+---------------+-------------+----------------------------+------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

**FAST (5.0)**

```
+----+---------------+--------+---------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | table         | type   | possible_keys             | key                    | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra                       |
+----+---------------+--------+---------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | S             | ref    | Sections_ParentID         | Sections_ParentID      | 5       | const                   |   10 | Using where; Using filesort | 
|  2 | ES            | index  | EventSection_EventID      | EventSection_EventID   | 10      | NULL                    | 5610 | Using where; Using index    | 
|  2 | MainEvent     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Event_DateTime,...| PRIMARY                | 4       | ES.EventSection_EventID |    1 | Using where                 | 
|  4 | Event_Website | ref    | EventWebsite_CompanyID    | EventWebsite_CompanyID | 4       | const                   | 5809 | Using where                 | 
|  3 | ChildEvent    | ref    | Event_ParentID            | Event_ParentID         | 5       | MainEvent.Event_ID      |    4 | Using where; Using filesort | 
+----+---------------+--------+---------------------------+------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you have the same indexes in the two databases?

Comment: @ypercube: yes; it's the exact same database, with a new version of mysql installed and mysql_upgrade run.

Comment: Just thought of reminding you to check that you have identical (besides the MySQL version) settings, tables, datatypes, indexes, engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions for rewriting:

1. Change `IN (SELECT ...)` to a `JOIN` query.
2. Change  `(SELECT COUNT(MainEvent.Event_ID) ...) > 0` to `EXISTS (SELECT * ...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was afraid I'd have to do something like this... now I have to try to locate where this query is running from. :(

Answer (score 1):

Mysql versions 5.0 and 5.1 (and all lower versions) are not the best versions to use when working with (dependent) sub-queries in this way.

If you are stuck on those versions try re-writing your queries to joins. Also using

> "{columnname} IN (SELECT .... FROM {tablename} WHERE ....)"

Is often a performance killer. Splitting it out to 2 queries is often faster then using that syntax.

Do the first query, get all the ID's needed, then place these id's in the above query

> "{columnname} IN (12, 345, 356, 653, etc...)"

MariaDB has partially solved this, and is a drop-dead MySQL replacement. If there is no sensitive data, can you send me database dump, and I will benchmark the above query on MariaDB

Comment: I get the exact same performance hit in MariaDB, which makes me think that the query is relying on some bug or optimization path that was fixed in 5.1 and common to all later versions.

Comment: edited question to reflect that it's not just 5.1 that's the problem, it's all versions after 5.0; 5.1 is just the first where it shows up.

Comment: Are you able to rewrite your query to make use of joins? Could you post your database schema?

Comment: @tylerl: You could also try the latest [MariaDB 5.3.3-rc](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/mariadb-533-release-notes) It's only a release candidate and not stable yet but it has several optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten your query, now it uses JOINS. I couldn't test this query because you haven't attached db schema. Please attach it to your question.

```
SELECT S.Sections_ID, S.Sections_Name, S.Sections_CustomURL
FROM Sections AS S
JOIN Event_Section AS ES ON ES.EventSection_SectionID = S.Sections_ID
JOIN Event AS MainEvent ON ES.EventSection_EventID = MainEvent.Event_ID
JOIN Event_Website ON Event_Website.EventWebsite_EventID = MainEvent.Event_ID
LEFT JOIN Event AS ChildEvent ON ChildEvent.Event_ParentEventID = MainEvent.Event_ID
WHERE S.Sections_Status = 'Active'
    AND S.Sections_Name != 'Hidden'
    AND S.Sections_ParentID = 0
    AND S.Sections_MainSection = 1
    AND (MainEvent.Event_ParentEventID = 0 OR MainEvent.Event_ParentEventID IS NULL)
    AND (MainEvent.Event_DateTime > '2011-12-27 18:05:00' OR ChildEvent.Event_DateTime > '2011-12-27 18:05:00')
    AND (MainEvent.Event_Status='Active' OR MainEvent.Event_Status='Canceled')
    AND Event_Website.EventWebsite_CompanyID = '3'
GROUP BY S.Sections_ID
ORDER BY S.Sections_Order ASC, S.Sections_Name ASC
```